# Issue with date format

Tags: objective-c, ios5

i'm trying to format a NSString given by array that includes a date in this format:

dd/MM/yyyy

and I'm trying to format it with this code:

```
NSDate *fechaDescuento = [[NSDate alloc] init];

        NSDateFormatter *dateformater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        NSString *baddate = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  descuento.fechaDescuento]];

        [dateformater setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

        [dateformater setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

        fechaDescuento = [dateformater dateFromString:baddate];
```

If bad date value, for instance, is 11/05/2012, fechaDescuento is formatted:

2012-05-10 22:00:00 +0000

Always one day before and with another format.

Please, can you help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: What time zone are you in? I'm guessing you have a -2 hour offset from London.

Comment: Also, the date itself is not formatted in any way, that's just its default description string. To output a date in the format of your choice, use a date formatter again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you add `[dateformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];` before  your `dateFromString:` call, I think it'll show you closer to what you expect.